# how to remux/fix video file saved with testdisk that reports error "Invalid NAL unit size"

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I have deleted a video file from an SD card and then 'undeleted' it with tool called testdisk for Linux. It saved complete file (6Gb), but video seems broken (can't be played by any video players) and ffprobe reports:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c613baef00] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1000
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c613baef00] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 1000.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c613baef00] Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it
[aac @ 0x55c613bb6dc0] channel element 3.6 is not allocated
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-2119335523 > 644375).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (1846222201 > 61596).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-864346179 > 57764).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (822755552 > 161099).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (188456672 > 131075).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-2009136561 > 113517).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-821906870 > 228207).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-516947408 > 120554).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (268246533 > 115897).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-1483463928 > 238451).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-1693450506 > 114421).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (1048922816 > 114846).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-600883429 > 357422).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-1612859848 > 93601).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-600474974 > 111975).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (321873764 > 211226).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-665491613 > 92183).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (258461639 > 95290).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (713914840 > 195792).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-556556768 > 93998).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-1864278243 > 94783).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-333442404 > 203732).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (1836887686 > 95706).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (125657193 > 96573).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-2049008956 > 342294).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (650110420 > 98067).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (694115932 > 100359).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (955742608 > 204098).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (1004021052 > 100944).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-885264782 > 100557).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Invalid NAL unit size (-1074298568 > 209804).
[h264 @ 0x55c613bb0cc0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c613baef00] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c613baef00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 29593 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MVI_1399.MP4':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2022-08-17T17:13:19.000000Z
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    make            : 
    make-eng        : 
    model           : 
    model-eng       : 
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1CAEP
  Duration: 00:29:59.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 29879 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(pc, bt709), 1920x1080, 29593 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-17T17:13:19.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 253 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-08-17T17:13:19.000000Z
```

I'm no programmer, but have used ffmpeg a lot. How can I remux (or even re-encode) such file to fix this and make the file usable for further work?

I have created a 10seconds snippet with `ffmpeg -i MVI_1399.MP4 -t 00:00:10 -c copy MVI_1399_10sec.mp4` for anyone to check. I also created a ten second snippet from a functioning clip from the same camera (I presume same codec parameters etc):

https://cb.emanat.si/s/WzTCxHDkzGw3gM3

Comment: For any sort of recovery attempt - I would need your entire 6 GB file without being touched by FFMPEG.

Comment: @Luka You need to "slice" the file somehow and then share a link of the file's first 20mb (or 30mb). You cannot pass it through FFmpeg first, because that will modify the bytes. We need a snippet of the original to check if playable or if anything can be extracted. **PS:** Don't have too much hope for a recovered video to play correctly. You might have 6gb of corrupted MP4 bytes.